# visual studio 2012 does not display wchar_t as text

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I just switched to visual studio 2012 from visual studio 2010 and I have a problem with visual studio 2012 debugger - it seems that when debugging c code wchar_t are no longer displayed as text.

just to simply, consider the following small and simple program:

```
#include <wchar.h>
int main()
{
  wchar_t *ppp = L"abcdef";
  char    *zzz = "abcedf";

  return 0;

}
```

in vs2012, when debugging this program, ppp watch displays "a"{97} and there is no magnifying glass that allow me to choose the visualization .
This is working well on vs2010, the watch display the entire text and showing the magnifying glass.

This also happen when hovering over the variable and when displaying its value in the immidiate window.chars are displayed correctly, the /Zc:wchar_t flag is set correctly, in fact I compiled the program in vs 2012 and just debugged it in vs2012 and vs2010 and got the same results, so it doesn't seems like a compilation problem.

Anyone encounter such a problem? are there any fixes or workarounds (beside forcing it by asking the value of ppp,su )?

Answer (score 10):

1. Put a breakpoint in your code inside your `main()`
2. Start your program and wait for the debug breakpoint to be hit
3. Right-click `ppp` with your mouse
4. Select *Add watch* in the pop-up window
5. Open the *Watch console*
6. Find `ppp`
7. Right-click `ppp`
8. Select *Edit value* in the pop-up window
9. Change "ppp" to "ppp,su" by appending ",su"

You should now see the content of `ppp` as Unicode text.

Debug operators that changes the default output are:

- su : Unicode text (UTF-16)
- s8 : UTF-8
- o : Octals
- d : Decimals
- x : Hexadecimals
- wc : Windows class
- wm : Windows message
- hr : HRESULT
- ! : turn off STL visualizations
- c : ASCII character

, and probably more.

Comment: + `s` for a normal string

Comment: if I want to watch not only the single unicode but the string, like p, 100, however, if added p,100, su, it will throw error. how to cope with it?

Comment: I found that we could use p,100su to display the p and the next 99 variable as unicode string. It is very useful when p is a struct pointer and there is unicode member in it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `,su` didn't work for me in a .c file.  Prefixing with `(wchar_t*)` did!